# Eligibility for a compensation under EC/261

Tags: europe, delays, compensation, air-france

I am a resident of EU. Recently, my Air France flight from Mumbai to Paris was cancelled. The ticket was booked by Air France but the flight was operated by Jet Airways. Air France gave a new flight scheduled to fly after 2 days, one extra layover and the travel time was increased from 15 hours to more than 30 hours (door to door).

The flight was rescheduled 14 days before the departure date but after we contacted the airline. The airline didn't contact us.

I wish to know if I am eligible for a compensation under the European Union implemented Regulation 261/2004 (hereafter known as EC/261).

Comment: I think I've seen somewhere that EC261 applicability is tied to the _operating carrier_ rather than the _marketing carrier_. It that is correctly remembered, you're out of luck EU-wise. But I can't quickly find where I saw that.

Answer (score 3):

**Unfortunately, you're not eligible for compensation under EC261.**

As stated on the [official website](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm) of the EU, EU passenger rights apply:

> If your flight arrives in the EU from outside the EU and is **operated by an EU airline**

This is then explained further:

> In some cases the airline *operating* the flight (also known as the operating air carrier) may not be the same as the one from which you bought your ticket. In case of any difficulties **only the airline which operates the flight** can be held responsible.

(Emphasis mine in all cases.)

Comment: That's disappointing ! I assumed the airline that booked my ticket is responsible for it as I have no control over the operating airline.